# How to create Ubuntu (running) base image to replicate on other environments.

Tags: docker

I've two question on how to build docker image from my running Ubuntu and Working project directory to base image with version

1) How to create base image from my running Ubuntu (14.0.4). It has MongoDB and other required dependency to support our application.

2) Based on Previous image, want to create base image for application (project directory) to created version zed images for deployments.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn a container into an image with `docker commit`:

```
# start a new ubuntu container, change some things and stop it again
$ docker run -it ubuntu
root@ca93ddb728ae:/# echo "changed image" > file
root@ca93ddb728ae:/# cat /file 
changed image
root@ca93ddb728ae:/# exit
exit

# the container still exists but it's stopped now
# turn it's current state into an image called 'my-ubuntu-image'
$ docker commit ca93ddb728ae my-ubuntu-image
sha256:47b71ccc78ae0b54598f153b1c999c01a9039b654e90da3a3ef3514b2f987df0

# start a container of our new 'my-ubunut-image' and find the previously
# changed file
$ docker run -it my-ubuntu-image
root@2732f428bf8a:/# cat /file 
changed image
```

After that you use your new image to build new ones as before. However, using a [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted/step_four/) is the recommended way to create your images.